# Prove that the equation $y^2=x^3-73$ has no integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Prove that there are no integers $x,y$ such that  $y^2=x^3-73$.
Thank you.

Comment: $(2a+1)^2+73=2(2a^2+2a+37)$ even but not divisible by $8,$ so $y$ must be even.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove") to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Equations of the form $y^2=x^3-k$ can sometimes be solved by purely elementary considerations, sometimes by factorization in the field with $\sqrt{-k}$, sometimes by factorization in the field with $\root3\of k$, and sometimes more advanced methods are needed. That's one reason it would be helpful to know the context in which you encountered the problem.

Comment: Why did this question get 5 upvotes?  Bad manners, no context or trace of effort on the poster's part.

Answer (score 3):

Equations of the form $$ y^2 = x^3 + k$$ are known as Bachet equations. I will quote the statement of Theorem 4.2 from Richard Mollin's Algebraic Number Theory:

> Let $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{k})$ be a complex quadratic field with
>   radicand $k< -1$ such that $k \neq 1 \pmod 4,$ and $h_{\mathfrak{D}_F}
>  \neq 0\pmod 3.$ Then there are no solutions to the Batchet equation in
>   integers $x,y$ except in the following cases: there exists an integer
>    $u$ such that $$(k,x,y) = (\pm 1-3u^2, 4u^2 \mp 1, \epsilon \cdot u(3
>  \mp 8u^2) ),$$
>
> where the $\pm$ signs correspond to the $\mp$ signs and $\epsilon =
>  \pm 1$ is allowed in either case.

Comment: Also known as Mordell's equation.

Comment: Do you know whether this field has class number divisible by $3$? If it does, the quote from Mollin doesn't help very much. Also, the equation is often referred to as the Mordell equation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Mathematica computes the class number to be 4.

Answer (score 1):

You should send the equation into the congruence modulo $4$, for that according to Division Algorithm, (or Complete Residue System modulo 4) we have 4 possibilities for arbitrary number $x$.

$$ \text{If}  \  x \equiv 0 \ \text{or} \ 2 \pmod{4} \ \ \text{then} \ \ y^2\equiv 0 - 73 \equiv 3 \equiv -1 \pmod{4} $$

So as we know in the congruence modulo $4$, it's not possible for a squared number (a number raised to the power of $2$) to be $-1$, all squared numbers are congruent to either $1$ or $0$ modulo $4$.

$$\text{If} \ \ x\equiv 3 \pmod{4}\ \ \text{then} \ \  y^2\equiv -1 -73\equiv2 \pmod{4} \ \ $$

And again it's not possible. The last part is $ x\equiv1\pmod{4} $ which is a little tricky! Look upon our equation and increase both side of it by $100$, the new equation will be: $$y^2+100=x^3+27 $$ By some algebraic factorising reformulate it like this: 
$$y^2+100=(x+3)(x^2-3x+9)\qquad (1)$$
If we take the single factor $(x^2-3x+9)$ and notice that $$x^2-3x+9 \equiv 1-3+9\equiv-1 \pmod{4}$$ 
Our game is started from now on, there must be an **odd** prime like $q$ in which, $q\equiv -1 \pmod{4}$ and $q \mid x^2-3x+9$.
Actually that's very convenient and there is an odd prime like $q$ because if we show $x^2-3x+9$ as the product of $p_1,p_2,...,p_k $ (note that it's possible for a pair or more than two of them like $p_i$ and $p_j$ to have $p_i=p_j$ and this will cover $p_1^\alpha p_2^\beta ...$ the true Unique-Prime-Factorization representation of numbers according to Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic) and neither every $p_i$ can be congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ nor the number of primes which are congruent to $-1$ is even. 
We show that the second part must be true, first we know every odd prime should be congruent to either $1$ or $-1$ modulo $4$ and also:
$$ x^2-3x+9 = p_1p_2...p_k \equiv 1\times 1\times ... (-1)\times (-1)\times ...\equiv (-1)^n \pmod{4}$$ So it's obvious for $n$ to be odd. Let's get back to our found $q$ and our customized equation (1). 
$$ y^2+100\equiv (x+3)(x^2-3x+9) \equiv 0 \pmod{q}$$ 
Therefore:
$$y^2 \equiv -100 \pmod{q}$$
$100=2^2\times 5^2$ and both $2$ and $5$ are primes and their remainders when they're divided by 4 are 2 and 1. So $2 \nmid q, q\nmid 5$ or better say $\text{gcd}(5,q)=\text{gcd}(2,q)=\text{gcd}(2\times 5,q)=1$, therefore there is an inverse of $10$ module $q$ and let denote it with $10\ '$, and multiply both sides of the congruence by $(10\ ')^2$:
$$ (10\ ')^2y^2\equiv -1 \pmod{q} $$
And we turn $10\ 'y$ into a new variable like $z$, therefore:
$$z^2\equiv -1 \pmod{q}$$ This congruence has solution if and only if $q\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ (according to a theorem which is resulted in by famous Wilson's Theorem), but our poor $q$ is congruent to $-1$ modulo $4$, and eventually we proved that  $y^2=x^3-73$ has no solution among integers.